Representability of Frobenius map for stacks
Let $\mathscr{X}$ be a quasicompact and quasiseparated algebraic stack over an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$. It is not too difficult to show that a Frobenius map for stacks can be defined, extending the natural definition of absolute Frobenius morphism for schemes. Let us denote this morphism by $F_{\mathscr{X}} : \mathscr{X} \rightarrow \mathscr{X}$. I have the following
Question : Is the map $F_{\mathscr{X}}$ representable by algebraic spaces? by schemes?
Thank you for your time.

A related morphism is representable by algebraic spaces. This is Proposition 4.13 in Tianwei Liang, Perfect algebraic stacks, https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.09951. Does this help somehow?

@MartinBrandenburg Thank you! This is helpful. Upon spending sometime on the article you mentioned, it seems that Prop. 5.31 says that the Frobenius map is itself representable by algebraic spaces. Perhaps this is the statement that I am looking for. But it appears at the end of the article and I am unable to follow the arguments well. Would you please consider explaining to me the essential arguments needed from the article to prove Prop 5.31? Thank you very much!

I cannot unfortunately, but I would suggest you update the question then, link to the proof and add specific questions about it.
